# Python Pandas to_clipboard() UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, unicode, clipboard

I want to pass dataframe data to my clipboard so I can paste into Excel.  Problem is, the character `'\xe9'` is causing an encoding issue, like so:

```
>>> df.to_clipboard()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\clipboard.py", line 65, in winSetClipboard
    hCd = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE, len(bytes(text))+1)
TypeError: string argument without an encoding

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#51>", line 1, in <module>
    df.to_clipboard()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1028, in to_clipboard
    clipboard.to_clipboard(self, excel=excel, sep=sep, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\clipboard.py", line 98, in to_clipboard
    clipboard_set(objstr)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\clipboard.py", line 68, in winSetClipboard
    hCd = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE, len(bytes(text, 'ascii'))+1)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 543793: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I decoded the character and it's an accent `é`

```
>>> '\xe9'.encode().decode()
'é'
```

After reading the documentation for [to_clipboard()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_clipboard.html), I noticed it says:
**other keywords are passed to `to_csv`**.  OK, so by 'other keywords', I assume that means keyword arguments from [to_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) -- specifically I want to use `encoding='cp1252'`.

When I try this, `to_clipboard()` doesn't recognize the `encoding` keyword:

```
df.to_clipboard(encoding='cp1252')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1028, in to_clipboard
    clipboard.to_clipboard(self, excel=excel, sep=sep, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\clipboard.py", line 95, in to_clipboard
    objstr = obj.to_string(**kwargs)
TypeError: to_string() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'
```

Is there a way to pass all data to the clipboard (both ascii and non-ascii)?

Comment: I reproduced the issue but could not fix it and it messed up my clipboard so was unable to cut and paste in any app without closing IPython.  Perhaps you could just write the df to a file, cvs or excel.

Comment: Have exactly the same issue (with `encode='utf-8'`) s would love to know if there is a solution to this issue! (strangely this doesn't always happen but only in some cases)

Answer (score 1):

```
df.to_clipboard(df.to_csv(encoding='cp1252'))
```

just encode it as a csv with the encoding specified then throw it on the clipboard.